# Installing Redmine on openSUSE

Tags: opensuse, configuration, redmine

I installed `redmine-1.1.3-1.1` on a openSUSE 12.1 using the repositories http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/tools:/scm/openSUSE_12.1 . Anyway, after the installation: I edited the `database.yml` file to add the mysql location on other server.

This way:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine
  host: <mysql-host>
  username: redmine
  password: <redmine.passwd.on.mysql>
  encoding: utf8
```

then I started the redmine (rcredmine start)

```
 # rcredmine start
redirecting to systemctl
```

an looks like it's working.

```
 # rcredmine status
redirecting to systemctl
redmine.service - LSB: Redmine Web Server
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/redmine)
          Active: active (exited) since Mon, 05 Mar 2012 15:32:27 -0200; 9s ago
         Process: 4601 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/redmine stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 4683 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/redmine start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/redmine.service
```

when I watch the logs don't show me anything strange.

```
 # tail -f /var/log/messages
Mar  5 15:32:27 redmine redmine[4683]: Starting Redmine daemon..done
```

There's no port at all

```
~ # netstat -nat | grep 3000
~ #
```

What I am missing?

Comment: What is the problem? What are you doing to test if it is working?

Comment: Im trying to see the like the demo page http://demo.redmine.org/

Answer (score 1):

you need install redmine by hands for understanding and training.

redmine required many gems (some with native compilation), 3 database conns in config (production, devel, test), database initialisation.

i have many error with fresh package (gem version check errors in rake-script).

and from 1 hour:

NetBeansProjects/redmine>

```
ruby bin/rails server -e test
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: duplicated key at line 466 ignored: "inodot"
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in test on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-12-11 00:40:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-12-11 00:40:54] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2015-12-11 00:40:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=23123 port=3000
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-4 Q16 x86_64  http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to browse to your redmine webpage via [http://localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000/), are you getting a "can't establish connection" or "connection refused" error?  Did you start the webrick as described in step 8 on [the redmine install instructions](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall):

```
ruby script/server webrick -e production
```

You may need to open port 3000 in your YaST firewall.

More specifics about your exact problem or errors will help.

Followup:  since you have rcredmine started, what about the standard web port 80?

Comment: found an error, trying the instalation from scratch and when I try to add the gem of mysql on ruby it does not work. In the other hand when I do the same in ubuntu it has not problem at all. So I will keep my ubuntu instalation as the first choise. thanks do.

Answer (score 0):

the full steps to a proper Redmine installation can be found here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

need to install bundler to make the gem collector.

```
 gem install bundler
```

is something goes wrong need to carefully read the output of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simpler time installing Redmine I'll point you towards the btinami stack of it, which just means it has things like apache packaged in with it and a few scripts that make installation simple.

https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine

It acts more like installing from windows, it'll ask you questions here and there, but does most of the work for you.